appending string to txt file only appends first letter python
with open("words_alpha.txt", 'r') as f:
  your_result = [line.split(',') for line in f.read().splitlines()]

for i in your_result:
  for word in i:
    x = len(word)
    print(word)
    if x == 1:
      with open("1.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(word)
    if x == 2:
      with open("2.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(word)

    if x == 3:
      with open("3.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(word)

    if x == 4:
      with open("4.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(word)
    if x == 5:
      with open("5.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(word)

    if x == 6:
      with open("6.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(word)

    if x == 7:
      with open("7.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(word)
    if x == 8:
      with open("8.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(word)

    if x == 9:
      with open("9.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(word)

    if x == 10:
      with open("10.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(word)
    if x == 11:
      with open("11.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(word)

    if x == 12:
      with open("12.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(word)r 

the code prints the word from a wordlist correctly, but when the same variable is appended, it only adds the first letter to each file. the code outputs the words line by line, but when appended, only shows up as a bunch of letters. the alpha words txt file is a wordlist with words on every line. i want to sort the words by letter count

Why do you have an if-chain instead of en elif chain?  Using if where elif is more appropriate is both deceptive and inefficient.

What are you going to do with the files 1.txt, 2.txt, ...,  after running the script? Giving more context would help us give better advice

"i want to sort the words by letter count" To clarify: Can you give a sample input file and expected output?

"the alpha words txt file is a wordlist with words on every line": are there wordS in every line or just one word per line? because your code should work for the former. maybe some lines are empty or contain just one word?

https://replit.com/@soapy75/sorter#main.py
this is the code and files

@Soapy From the file words_alpha.txt at replit, it looks like there is one word per line. Why are you using line.split(',') then? Also, clarify what the expected output should look like for this input file

You should share your input file example and your expected output file format.

I would define a function for this task:
If your words_alpha.txt looks like:
Alpha
Beta
Gamma
…

with open("words_alpha.txt", 'r') as f:
  your_result = [line.split(',') for line in f.read().splitlines()]

def append_file(word, length):
    with open(f"{length}.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(f"\n{word}")
        print(f"word: {word} with length {length} written in {length}.txt")
            
for word in your_result:
    append_file(str(*word), int(len(*word)))

If you have a comma separated list, like:
Alpha, Beta, Gamma, … , one the same row, than this code should be used:

with open("words_alpha.txt", 'r') as f:
    your_result = [line.split(',') for line in f.read().splitlines()]

def append_file(word, length):
    with open(f"{length}.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(word+'\n')
        print(f"word: {word} with length {length} written in {length}.txt")
            
for row in your_result:
    for word in row:
        append_file(word.lstrip(), len(word.lstrip()))


The output files n.txt will write each word in a new line.
For a comma separated list ( csv) use better the csv reader():
import csv

def append_file(word, length):
    with open(f"{length}.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(word+'\n')
        print(f"word: {word} with length {length} written in {length}.txt")

with open("words_alpha.txt", 'r') as csvfile:
    cr = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in cr:
        for word in row:
            append_file(word.strip(','), len(word.strip(',')))


In for word in i you are iterating over the characters of every word, you need to remove this loop. Another issue is how you read the words_alpha file, no need to split anything or iterate over the words. You should also replace all the if conditions with a generic solution
with open("words_alpha.txt", 'r') as f:
    your_result = f.readlines()

for word in your_result:
    x = len(word)
    print(word)
    with open(f"{x}.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(f"{word}\n")

